# Optimus Bumblebee Performance

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 and Bumblebee, I tested out the performance of the Nvidia card using Minecraft and a few other games. I've noticed it to be way slower than it was on Windows 7. Is this normal? I'm using the GT 630m. From what I've read online, nobody has said it to be slower than Windows. I'm just really curious because I want to use Linux so much more than Windows, but if I don't get the same performance I feel really picky.

The Nvidia card is still faster than my Intel graphics on Ubuntu, but it's not as fast as it was for my on Windows.

I get 60 - 80 fps on Minecraft on windows, while I get 28 - 48 fps on Ubuntu.

Any Ideas why? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is slower. A performance test shows it can be slowe like 1/8th of windows. This is because of the use of `virtualgl` to generate the images.

The only to get full performance is to connect external monitor via hdmi port and run the required application there. This also depends on the wiring of hardware. If your HDMI port is directly connected to nvidia chip, you can do it.

This answer was given by the author  of bumblebee (Lekensteyn) in this site. Unfortunately I forgot the link.

Related Links:

---

[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/35775)

[Bumblebee FAQ](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ)

Comment: Thanks so much. That's what I thought, but wasn't fully sure.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option that you can try, which is `primusrun` instead of `optirun`. If you have a recent installation of Bumblebee, you already have it installed. `Primusrun` uses a different approach to `virtualgl`, and has shown better performance in many cases.

http://raw.github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/master/doc/RELEASE_NOTES_3_1